# C++ Storing a list of addresses to array to parse raw non terminated text?

Tags: c++, string, parsing, text

I'm just starting out programming but I've had a lot of ideas about how to make my life easier when parsing files by making a program that maps addresses of data when read into memory from a file.

Note: I cut down the wall text here's the problem in a nutshell

How does one parse an array of chars with no null terminator but the words all begin with uppercase letters so Capital can be used as delimiter?

Basically I want to parse text file that is just 'WordWordWord' and send each word to a to it's own separate string variable then be able to write each word to a text file with a newline added.

I wanted to do some more advanced stuff but I was asked to cut the wall of text so that will do for now :)

```
//pointers and other values like file opening were declared
int len = (int) strlen( words2 );

cout << "\nSize of Words2 is  : " << len << " bytes\n";

// Loops through array if uppercase then...     
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {

        if (isupper(words2[i]))
        {

        // Output the contents of words2

    cout << "\n Words2 is upper : " << words2[i] << "\n";
        b1 = &words2[i];

    //output the address of b1 and the intvalue of words2[var]

    cout << "\nChar address is  " << &b1 << " word address is " << (int) words2[i] << "\n";
        cout << "\nChar string is  " << b1 << " address +1 "<< &b1+1 <<"\n  and string is " << b1+1 << "\n";

        }
        cout << "\nItem I is : i " << i << " and words2 is  " << words2[i] << "\n";

    }


    fin.clear();
    fin.close();
    fout.close();
```

Comment: shorten your text.. I don't want to waste time reading all this :) and since nobody answered yet I guess I'm not the only one... write short and clear; and give examples..

Answer (score 1):

Easy. Use [Boost.Tokenizer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/tokenizer/index.html), with `char_separator("", "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")`. `""` is the set of dropped separators, and A-Z is the set of kept separators. (If you'd used A-Z as dropped separators, you'd get `ord ord ord` because you'd drop the W.)

Answer (score 0):

Since you also

> wanted to do some more advanced stuff

I would have a look a [Boost.Regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html) from the get go.  This is a good library for doing textual manipulations.

Answer (score 0):

```
vector<char *> parsedStrings;
char * words = "HelloHelloHello";
int stringStartAddress = 0;

for (int i = 0; i <= strlen(words); i++)
{
    /* Parses word if current char is uppercase or
     if it's the last char and an uppercase char was previously matched */
    if (isupper(words[i]) || ((i == strlen(words)) && (stringStartAddress != 0)))
    {
        // Current char is first uppercase char matched, so don't parse word
        if (stringStartAddress == 0)
        {
            stringStartAddress = ((int)(words + i));
            continue;
        }
        int newStringLength = ((int)(words + i)) - stringStartAddress;
        char * newString = new char[newStringLength + 1];
        // Copy each char from previous uppercase char up to current char 
        for (int j = 0; j < newStringLength; j++)
        {
            // Cast integer address of char to a char pointer and then get the char by dereferencing the pointer
            // Increment address to that of the next char
            newString[j] = *((char *)stringStartAddress++);
        }
        newString[newStringLength] = '\0'; // add null-terminator to string
        parsedStrings.push_back(newString);
    }
}
```